# How to get "all users that made edits on a bbox" in overpass?

Tags: overpass-api

I need all the users that made edits on a bbox. I know about the `node (user:"username")(bbox)out meta;`. What I need is something like this `node (user:".*")(bbox)out meta;`. But the problem is, it is not showing any result. I don't think you can you regex when ':' operator is used. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overpass API will only return those users who performed the *last* edit of an OSM object. It **cannot** provide a list of all users, who ever contributed to an OSM object, as you might know it from an [OSM object's history](http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/210409787/history).

Here's an Overpass QL query fetching all user names for ways and nodes in the current bbox, who last edited the respective OSM object. I choose CSV output format, as this is the only information you're interested in. In a post processing step, you still have to remove duplicates.

```
[out:csv(::user)];
(node({{bbox}});
 way({{bbox}}););
out meta;
```

Try it in overpass turbo: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/beM

Comment: This is helpful. I was not clear about the overpass returning the newest edits. Thank you.